# Expected type 'Union[ndarray, Iterable]' warning in Python instruction

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, warnings, translate

I have translated a Matlab function to create an Overcomplete Discrete Cosine Transform matrix to represent 1D signals in such vectorial space, to Python language.

## Matlab Function

```
function D = odctdict(n,L)
%ODCTDICT Overcomplete DCT dictionary.
%  D = ODCTDICT(N,L) returns the overcomplete DCT dictionary of size NxL
%  for signals of length N.
%
%  See also ODCT2DICT, ODCT3DICT, ODCTNDICT.    

D = zeros(n,L);
D(:,1) = 1/sqrt(n);
for k = 2:L
  v = cos((0:n-1)*pi*(k-1)/L)';
  v = v-mean(v);
  D(:,k) = v/norm(v);
end
```

## Python translated function

```
import numpy as np


def odct1dict(n, l):
    """
    1-D Overcomplete DCT dictionary.

    D = odct1dict(N, L) returns the overcomplete DCT dictionary of size NxL
    for signals of length N.

    :param n: signal size
    :type n: int
    :param l: number of atoms
    :type l: int
    :return: 1-D Overcomplete DCT dictionary NumPy array
    """

    d = np.zeros((n, l))
    d[:, 0] = 1 / np.sqrt(n)

    for k in range(1, l):
        v = np.transpose(np.cos(np.arange(0, n) * np.pi * k * l))
        v = v - np.mean(v)
        d[:, k] = v / np.linalg.norm(v)

    return d
```

I'm using PyCharm as Python IDE, and this software raises a warning, that I don't understand, in the instruction `v = np.transpose(np.cos(np.arange(0, n) * np.pi * k * l))` inside the for loop, specifically for the argument of the `np.transpose` function, `np.cos(np.arange(0, n) * np.pi * k * l)`.

> Expected type 'Union[ndarray, Iterable]', got 'int' instead less...
>
> This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due
>   to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but
>   useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified
>   in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.

Can you explain this warning for me? And how to correct it? What is the proper way to write such instruction?

Comment: Can you can expand that expression into multiple steps, so you can see which one fails?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing that PyCharm does not fully understand numpy.  It looks and acts like valid Python:

Using my IDE, `Ipython`, I can do:

```
In [84]: n,k,l=3, .4, 1

In [85]: v = np.transpose(np.cos(np.arange(0, n) * np.pi * k * l))

In [86]: v
Out[86]: array([ 1.        ,  0.30901699, -0.80901699])
```

Answer (score 10):

These false positives happen a lot with numpy code in PyCharm. In a [thread discussing this issue with JetBrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000143004-Incorrect-warnings-in-Pycharm-2017-1), they say:

> Almost any code written in reasonably elegant numpy style gets drowned in warning messages.

For arguments of your own functions you can [write docstrings to let PyCharm know what type to expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318814/how-can-i-tell-pycharm-what-type-a-parameter-is-expected-to-be). For a lot of numpy code however this will not be relevant. There are two solutions I found:

1. Suppress the warnings per-line or per-function with the line `# noinspection PyTypeChecker` before the line or function where the warning occurs. See the [official guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/suppressing-inspections.html) for more details on suppressing warnings
2. Use [type hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374526/2260153):

   ```
   transpose_arg = np.cos(np.arange(0, n) * np.pi * k * l)  # type: np.ndarray
   v = np.transpose(transpose_arg)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To append to buzjwa's answer:

**Option 3:** Use mypy for type checking and manually add the 3rd party stub file created for numpy [here](https://github.com/machinalis/mypy-data/tree/master/numpy-mypy)

You will need to add this stub file to your internal python typeshed. Let us know how you get on!